# Customize the "Select input method" Dialog

Tags: android, root, android-dialog, android-input-method

I think we all have seen in an Android device the "Select Input Method" dialog:

[image: http://img.wonderhowto.com/img/91/76/63510288127834/0/type-more-accurately-efficiently-your-samsung-galaxy-s3-with-wordwaves-intelligent-keyboard.w654.jpg]

I have seen in several places different dialogs, customized for the different environments. For example, from the App Spanish for GO Keyboard:

[image: https://lh3.ggpht.com/RNvSBWYWomrQxrwatPe-usvCyA-1r6PlrwjIlTvcJT7ISE5g4R7fxKnUM8oEJSLABWw=h310]

I am fully aware that this **does REQUIRE ROOT**. That is ok, the App will only work in rooted devices.

So, I want to customize this popup (and also being able to select the displayed options). But I have absolutely no clue about how to do it. Can anyone give a hint about how I should proceed?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end the best solution was simple and didn't even require rooting: Create a custom keyboard with a 'KeyboardView' object and set this keyboard in the required way.